# Unable to generate pdf from HTML using Doppio

Tags: laravel, html-to-pdf, doppio

I am trying to use https://doc.doppio.sh/guide/cookbook/protected-url.html to convert a html to pdf. On this one, since my url is password protected I am having it difficult to print the page.

My code:

```
 $client = new \GuzzleHttp\Client();
        $response = $client->post('https://api.doppio.sh/v1/render/pdf/sync', [
            'headers' => [
                'Accept'     => 'application/json',
                'Authorization' => 'Bearer apikey',
                'Content-Type' => 'application/json'
            ],
            'json' => [
                'page' => [
                    "pdf" => [
                        "printBackground" => true
                    ],
                    "goto" => [
                        "url" => 'https://example.com/admin/property'
                    ],
                    "authenticate" => [
                        "username" => 'user@domain.com',
                        "password" => 'password'
                    ],
                ]
            ]
        ]);
        $responseBody = $response->getBody();
```

This is printing the page, however instead it is printing the login page. Its because when user is not authenticated, the system will redirect user to the login page.

Here, it has also mentioned about the `https://doc.doppio.sh/guide/cookbook/protected-url.html#using-cookies` cookie methods,however, I don't know what cookie should I pass on which name.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is more related to how does the login/auth works on the page you try to convert.

The "authenticate" prop you use here is related to [HTTP Basic Authentication](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basic_access_authentication) and I am not sure its what the page you want to access is using.

If you manually login into the page, check your browser, what is happening ? Do you see cookies ?

Comment: yes, its does login, I tried passing email and password, it throws: `Client error: `POST https://api.doppio.sh/v1/render/pdf/sync` resulted in a `400 Bad Request` response: {"statusCode":400,"message":["page.authenticate.property email should not exist","page.authenticate.username must be sho`, and if I pass username instead, it just print the login page.

Comment: HTTP Basic Authentication is a protocol on its own, are you sure it is what your app is using ? What is your cookie name in your laravel app ? You need to set a value for that